# Can't get my div to reach the top and sides of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin, padding

I can't get my div to cover the top and sides of the page. There is a weird gap. This div is within a body tag. I added margin and padding to zero for the body and the div. It won't go away.

```
<style scoped>
body {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

#navdiv {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgb(31, 32, 32);
    border-bottom: 0.05rem dotted black;
    padding: 1.0rem;

}

a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  color: white;
}


</style>

<template>
  <div id="navdiv">
    <nav id="nav1" @mouseover="mouseOver">
      <div v-show="active">show</div>
      <router-link v-for="routes in links" 
      v-bind:key="routes.id"
      :to="`${routes.page}`">{{routes.text}}</router-link>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please add your code here. Not the screenshot alone.

Comment: @ManojKumar added above

Comment: Please add html code of that portion.

Comment: added at the bottom!

Comment: Your code doesn't show the problem you are describing. Check the width and position of all of the parent divs of the div.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `margin: 0; padding:0`
like so:

```
template, div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: "The HTML Content Template (<template>) element is a mechanism for holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript." is your JavaScript loading it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template